# Python class object has no attribute "func_name"

Tags: python, class, data-structures

I'm creating a data structure for creating dispute tickets, which stores many dispute types. Each dispute type has its own class derived from a base class, which simply defines basic attributes such as the name of the dispute type. the Disputes class is the interface through which the user generates requests. The problem is that the generate_dispute function is not being recognized.

```
class BaseDispute:
    name = None

class dispute_type_foo(BaseDispute):
    name = 'foo'

    def response(self):
        return "foo"

class Disputes: 
    instance = None
    class __Disputes:
        types = {
            "foo":dispute_type_foo
        }

    def generate_dispute(self,type):
        if type in self.instance.types:
                        return self.instance.types[type]()

def __new__(cls):
    if not cls.instance:
        cls.instance = cls.__Disputes()
    return cls.instance

@staticmethod
def getInstance():
    return Disputes()


manager = Disputes.getInstance()
dispute = manager.generate_dispute('foo')
if dispute is not None:
    print(dispute.response())
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Disputes.py", line 61, in <module>
dispute = manager.generate_dispute('RC75')
AttributeError: Disputes instance has no attribute 'generate_dispute'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `.getInstance()`? It looks like you're trying to go from `Java` to `Python`, is this a correct assumption? Just realized you are trying to create a declaration for `Disbuptes()`. Is you indentation wrong? Because `__new__` is tabbed wrong for the declration to be inherited for `Disputes`

Comment: I'm following the Singleton-pattern design for this class, which takes object creation out of the programmer's hands and does it programatically. Basically, this class will eventually auto-add new dispute classes to the master list, instead of the programmer explicitly adding them. i.e. to add a new dispute, simply drag and drop its class file into the folder and this Disputes class will see it and run code to add it.

Comment: This is ... not Python. What's the point of the nested `__Disputes` class? And the indentation is all over the place.

Comment: Its time you get the indentation right, before posting the problem. Its difficult to understand what this program intends to.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that the problem is with indentation, as the indentation is clearly off (there are methods outside of classes) and using nested classes with messed up indentation could explain the problems.

Comment: I'm scrapping the Singleton pattern after reading about some of its detractors. Disregard, I'm moving back to a normalized class structure.

Comment: And the problems with indentation are because copying and pasting code and maintaining accurate indentation is something apparently I can't do on this site.